# is Qt's event loop is FIFO?

Tags: c++, qt

When you send a signal into a thread that it is not the GUI thread (by instance from a socket thread), the signal is enqueued in the event loop of the receiver's thread.(I believe this, tell me if I am wrong)

I am wondering if this queue is FIFO ? I can't find it with google..

Comment: I thought a queue was FIFO by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 5,820,000 results on Google for `qt signal queue fifo`, the first having in its result summary the following wording from Qt's documentation:

> A queue is a first in, first out (FIFO) structure.

So, where they've used the term "queue", they indeed mean FIFO as the word implies anyway.

This would also be easy to test for yourself.

Comment: are you sure that Qt signal queue use QQueue ?

Comment: @Guillaume07: It doesn't matter whether it does or not. This wording sets the precedent for what Qt means by the term "queue". As it turns out, they mean the same thing by it that the rest of the world does. :) Really, it would make _no_ sense to implement a signal queue any other way.

Comment: I agree yes.I have a hard bug in production code, and I just want to be sure with my hypothesis, thanks.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that might appear to screw up the FIFO behaviour is calling processEvents().  If you are doing that, stop it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Martin James is right, it is not a strict FIFO at all, events can be posted with a priority and they are only a strict FIFO within the same priority - outside of that they are in priority order.  I also cannot find anything in the docs that says 'normal' Qt events are sent using the `Qt::NormalEventPriority`, meaning there is no guarantee of FIFO behaviour.

Comment: @cmannett85 So I do believe that the proper term here would be more like **priority queue** and not a **FIFO**. If all priorities are equal then we have a FIFO, otherwise it most certainly is not a FIFO (as you have mentioned).

Comment: @cmannett85: Arguably then it's actually multiple FIFOs running back-to-back. From a logical standpoint.